# Laravel Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to collect data of my products from 3rd table and I get

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

## LOGIC

1. `custom_product_specifications` table gets `product_id`,
   `specification_id`,`text_dec` & `longtext_dec`
2. If product that user is visiting has id in `custom_product_specifications` I will show `specification title`base on it's id.
3. I will show data of `text_dec` & `longtext_dec`

## Codes

`CustomProductSpecification Model`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomProductSpecification extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
      'product_id', 'specification_id', 'text_dec', 'longtext_dec',
    ];

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function specifications(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Specification::class,'custom_product_specifications', 'specification_id');
    }
}
```

`Product Model`

```
    public function customsubspecifications(){
         return $this->belongsToMany(CustomProductSpecification::class, 'custom_product_specifications', 'product_id', 'specification_id');
      }

public function specifications(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Specification::class);
  }
```

`Specification Model`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Specification extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
      'title',
  ];

  public function subspecifications(){
     return $this->hasMany(Subspecification::class);
  }

  public function sets(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Set::class);
  }

  public function customproductspecifications(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(CustomProductSpecification::class);
  }


}
```

### Here is how I get data in my view

`controller`

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $productslug)->firstOrFail();
$customspecs = CustomProductSpecification::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)->get();
```

`blade`

```
@if(!empty($customspecs))
  @foreach($customspecs as $customspec)
    <tr>
      <th style="width:150px;">{{ $customspec->specifications->title }}</th>
       <th class="text-left">
        {{$customspec->text_dec}}
        {{$customspec->longtext_dec}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

## Result

If I use `{{ $customspec->specifications->title }}` I'll get error.

If I use `{{ $customspec->specifications}}` this is what I get:

[image: screenone]

One of my data has specification info (repeated) others just show `[]`

## Update

base on answers below I changed my `blade` code to:

```
@if(!empty($customspecs))
          @foreach($customspecs as $customspec)
            @foreach($customspec->specifications as $specification)
              <tr>
                <th style="width:150px;">{{ $specification->title }}</th>
                <th class="text-left">
                  @isset($customspec->text_dec)
                  {{$customspec->text_dec}}
                  @endisset
                  @isset($customspec->longtext_dec)
                  {{$customspec->longtext_dec}}
                  @endisset
                </th>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          @endforeach
        @endif
```

There 2 issue here:

1. I cannot get all of my data
2. They are not implode (not in `specifications` nor in `details`)

#### Screenshots

`my database`

[image: dbscreen]

PS: it will loads only my last input which is `id:4`

`Blade Results`

[image: bladescreen]

PS: I get my input `id:4` repeated `3` times while I should get `4` results with different info.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CustomProductSpecification` and `Specification` relateted with `belongs to many` relations. You must be use this code

```
@if(!empty($customspecs))
  @foreach($customspecs as $customspec)
    <tr>
    @foreach($customspec->specifications as $specification)
      <th style="width:150px;">{{ $specification->title }}</th>
    @endforeach
      <th class="text-left">
        {{$customspec->text_dec}}
        {{$customspec->longtext_dec}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Hi there, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel automatically converts your response from the Query into a collection and it respects your "with" parameters and creates a join query in order to give you all the data you requested but what happens is, there are cases when there is actually no record from the child table so laravel will assume it is null and put your relation property equal to []. In a foreach loop when you are trying to use a property from a [] object you get that error.

There are many ways to solve this error as stated above but I would advice you to understand why this error occurs so that you will have a better understanding of laravel collection, relationships and how every result from the database table is converted for your convenience.

## Method #1

use empty() function to check if the value exists on that property and that it is not null.

## Method #2 :

Laravel Blade has a sugar for it which you can find here : https://laravel-news.com/blade-or-operator

## Method #3 : (I would not recommend this)

use the error suppressor operator "@" right before when you are trying to access that property.

## Method #4 : (Slow method and increases business logic on the controller and view)

Construct a new array in the controller before sending it to the view by using control statements.

## Method #5 :

Laravel Blade as @isset directive. You can use that too. More details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#control-structures).